# how to find boxsizers by name in wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to add a new sizer dynamically to an existing nested sizer. I was able to get pointer to main window sizer using GetSizer() function, but I cannot find any function which can search for a sizer by name. I also tried GetChildren function which gave me a list of pointers , but I don't know how to identify the nested sizer in the list by name.

Answer (score 0):

The BoxSizer class doesn't have a name argument, so you cannot find a sizer by name. You could create a dictionary and put your BoxSizers in there:

```
mydict = {"topSizer":topSizer, "othersizer":differentBoxSizer}
```

Or you could just make the sizer objects into class attributes:

```
self.mySizer
```

Then you can refer to "self.mySizer" anywhere in the class.

Comment: I am using wxFormBuilder to create the gui. For some reason wxFormBuilder creates sizers  without "self" prefix in init function.

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need to refer to the sizers later, so that's probably why FormBuilder does that. You might find the Widget Inspection Tool helpful as it can actually highlight sizers: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool